# Correctly align part items in Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, alignment, parts

The following code exemplifies the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Apple}
\section{Pig}
\section{Ant}
\section{Whale}
\part{Banana}
\section{Hammer}
\section{Saw}

\end{document}
```

[image: Misaligned part items]

The two parts are not aligned horizontally, but especially the part *Banana* is clearly misaligned with the section items below it. I guess it is because the widths with roman numerals are different. The table of contents looks ugly!

I could write `\part{ Apple}` (space before name) which horizontally aligns *Apple* with *Banana*, but both will still not be aligned with the section items.

**Tip?:** You can use the `\part*{}` command prefixed with `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{part name}`

Comment: How many parts does your document have? As many as VIII (aka "8")?  Please advise.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why does your document, which uses the `report` class, employ `\part` and `\section` directives but (apparently) no `\chapter` directives?

Comment: You could check `titletoc` package https://mirror.quantum5.ca/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf

Comment: The problem is, that `report` does not use `\numberline{…}` for the part entries. With `scrreprt` or `memoir` it is much easier, because these classes use (a kind of) `\numberline{…}` for the part entries. Try, e.g., `\documentclass[11pt,numbers=noenddot,sfdefaults=false]{scrreprt}` to see the difference.

Comment: @Mico: Good question! Didn't think about that. I've been using _report_ over _article_ almost from my beginning. This time I'm doing a A3 landscape presentation (with custom background using Inkscape). `\section{}` gives a more condensed header and text suitable in my case. I guess I could tweak the `\chapter{}` style (using _titlesec_?), but `\section{}` just works!

I only have 2 parts.

Comment: @cabohah @Mico @Tom : Looks like the answer to this question is "Use another documentclass"! cf. `\numberline{}`. the _memoir_ and _scrreprt_ classes created errors with my current code, so I couldn't use them directly. However, I realise I can use `\part*{}` and `\addcontentsline{}` since I don't need the (roman) part numbering this time. The question is still interesting. @cabohah: If you write an answer below about using a different documentclass, I will accept it as the answer.